# Google Play Console. Your app doesn't have any in-app products yet

Tags: java, android, billing

I want to add in-app-billing option in the app. In google documentation says that you need to add permission `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.venging.BILLING"/>` in `manifest` file. I added this permission, `IInAppBillingService.aidl` in the project and the the service. But developer console says "Your app doesn't have any in-app products yet, To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK.". Anyone had this problem? Do I need to wait until google will update the information?

**EDIT** Here is where aidl file located

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in your permission, it's supposed to be `"android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"`. Not sure if that's your issue or just a question typo, though, since you won't get an error upon compilation.

Comment: Oh my God! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo in your permission, it's supposed to be `"android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"`. This doesn't give a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uploaded an signed-apk with the permission and the .aidl file ?

It normally allows to add IAP after you uploaded and an signed apk with these files...